# Unable to communicate with client device using server script [Python socket]

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking

I am using Socket library of Python. There is a device (Ethernet to UART converter) in client mode, and my computer acts as server. I want to communicate with the device, I wrote a simple script but I when I run the program it stuck and does not move forward.
Here is my script:

```
import socket
import time
import signal
import numpy as np

#******************Commands**************************************
check_firm = [0x5A, 0x04, 0x01, 0x5F]
get_vol = [0x5A, 0x04, 0x09, 0x67]
#******************Commands**************************************
HEADER = 9 # size of bytes to receive
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!Disconnect"

PORT = 50001 # Arbitrary non-privileged port
computer_IP = "192.168.0.95"
ADDR = (computer_IP, PORT)

# set TCP/IP connnection
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
server.bind(ADDR)

    
print("[STARTING] Server is starting.....")
server.listen(1)
conn, addr = server.accept()
server.settimeout(10)
with conn:
        print("[Connected] by", addr)
        print(addr)
server.sendall(bytes(check_firm))
message = server.recv(7)
print("[INFO]" + str(message.hex()))
```

My program hangs at:

```
[STARTING] Server is starting.....
```

Any help or suggestions will highly be appreciated.
Note that when I change the mode of Ethernet to UART converter to server mode and run client script on my computer I can communicate with it.
Thank you

Comment: Looks like it is blocking inside `accept()`, waiting for the client to connect.  Note that you can usually leave `computer_IP` set to `''` so that the server will allow incoming connections from anywhere, not just `192.168.0.95`, but regardless you'll need to have the client connect to the server, the server can't initiate the connection.

Comment: In addition to what Jeremy had told, I would also suggest you to run a ping in terminal/command prompt to check that the connection is fine between client and server. You can also make sure that firewall or other elements are not blocking the connection.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, thank you for your response, I think this point makes sense "you'll need to have the client connect to the server, the server can't initiate the connection." that's why I am unable to connect when external device in client mode. But in server mode I can successfully connects because there is no way that I can run python script or any other way on external device, the only way is to use my computer in client mode and connect to external device. The external Ethernet to UART adapter doesn't seems to connect automatically I waited for long time and tried several times.

Comment: @ariharanvijayarangam thanks for suggestion ping works, and like I mentioned above I can connect when my computer is in client mode so it's not the issue of firewall I think. But Jeremy point makes sense.